# getting the position of items inside React Native FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flatlist, pressable

#### Scenario:

I've got a number of items inside `FlatList` and I'm showing a `Modal`, with item coordinates, on long-pressing any of the Items and closing it when the touch is released.

I'm using [Pressable](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable#onlongpress) for achieving long-press and `onLayout` to get the item coordinates.

`Item` component looks like this

```js
const Item = ({ data, toggleModal }) => {
  const [layout, setLayout] = React.useState(null);
  return (
    <Pressable
      style={styles.item}
      delayLongPress={300}
      onLayout={({ nativeEvent }) => {
        setLayout(nativeEvent.layout);
      }}
      onLongPress={() => {
        toggleModal(layout);
      }}
      onPressOut={() => {
        toggleModal(null);
      }}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{data}</Text>
    </Pressable>
  );
};
```

and the `App` component looks like this

```js
// imports

export default function App() {
  const data = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    visible: false,
    layout: { x: 0, y: 0, height: 0, width: 0 },
  });

  const toggleModal = (layout) => {
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      visible: !prevState.visible,
      layout,
    }));
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={({ item }) => item}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Item data={item} toggleModal={toggleModal} />
        )}
      />
      <Modal visible={state.visible}>
        <Button title={'Close'} onPress={toggleModal} />
        <Text>
          layout: x:{state.layout?.x}, y:{state.layout?.y}, height:
          {state.layout?.height}, width:{state.layout?.width}
        </Text>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
}
```

But the coordinates of all the items are the same no matter which item I press.

If I use [CellRendererComponent](https://reactnative.dev/docs/virtualizedlist#cellrenderercomponent) instead of `renderItem` I'm getting the correct coordinates but the `Modal` is not being closed.

```js
CellRendererComponent={({ item }) => (
  <Item data={item} toggleModal={toggleModal} />
)}
```

Using `ScrollView` works fine though.

Here's the [Expo Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@naresh-expo-namespace/mature-nachos)

Comment: are u solve it?